# How to read big chunk of data using fread and access them as an array in C

Tags: c, file, pointers, crash, malloc

I have a code with the goal of reading a binary file using **fread** and then processing the data and sending that to a **char *buffer** of size **1310720**

For now (with my working code) I was reading file byte by byte for doing some processing then writing the byte 1 by 1 into an `unsigned char array[i]`
I was using something like this

```
void read_input_file(FILE *stream,char *buffer)
{
    long i = 0;
    unsigned char tmp_buf[1310720] ;
    unsigned char *calc = malloc(1);
    while(i < 1310720)
    {
        fread(calc,1,1,stream);
        tmp_buf[i] = round(*calc /128);//this is an example
        i++;
    }
    
    memcpy(buffer, &tmp_buf[0], 1310720);
}
```

it was working but now I want (for performance reasons) to read chunk of data that are the size of the buffer.
So I tried using something like this :

```
void read_input_file(FILE *stream,char *buffer)
{
    long i = 0;
    unsigned char tmp_buf[1310720] ;
    unsigned char *calc = malloc(1310720);

    fread(calc,1310720,1,stream);

    while(i < 1310720)
    {
        tmp_buf[i] = round(calc[i] /128);//this is an example
        i++;
    }
    
    memcpy(buffer, &tmp_buf[0], 1310720);
}
```

but whatever I do I got execution error where the program crash. I tried a lot of different things and code but nothing works.

**So how do I read a big chunk of data into a buffer and then access it byte by byte to process the data ?**

Comment: What happens with the code on the bottom? What is the problem?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: Are you on Windows?  The stack size limit on Windows is 1024 KiB (1 MiB) and you're trying to create a 1280 KiB buffer on the stack.  Use dynamic memory allocation twice.  Even on Unix-like systems, the stack size limit is typically 8 MiB, so allocating that large of an array on the stack is a little dubious.

Comment: You're also leaking memory in the code shown — you don't free `calc` before returning.  I assume that the lack of error checking is to simplify the code for SO, but don't omit error checking (on `malloc()` and `fread()`) in your real code.  And why use the intermediate buffer?  Why not simply copy the processed data byte-by-byte into the output buffer?  One reason could be 'transactional integrity'.  If something goes wrong, you don't want to modify `buffer` at all.  Then the intermediate result is reasonable.  You should also pass the buffer size as a parameter to the function for checking.

Comment: what's the point of `tmp_buf`? Can't you read directly into `buffer`?

Comment: yes i'm on Windows (the free i forget about it on the example code)

Comment: @gog the goal of ```tmp_buf``` is to store the processed data

Comment: i need to do it in 2 step cause im sending all in one all the data to a device with **libusb** that why i do a memcpy off ```tmp_buf``` when the array it is full (i works on a fork so I'm only editing data before sending to the buffer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you are working on [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74141688/how-to-read-big-chunk-of-data-using-fread-and-access-them-as-an-array-in-c#comment130903260_74141688), the problem is what I outlined in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74141688/how-to-read-big-chunk-of-data-using-fread-and-access-them-as-an-array-in-c#comment130902901_74141688):

> The stack size limit on Windows is 1024 KiB (1 MiB) and you're trying to create a 1280 KiB buffer on the stack. Use dynamic memory allocation twice. Even on Unix-like systems, the stack size limit is typically 8 MiB, so allocating that large of an array on the stack is a little dubious.

Because your `tmp_buf` variable is created as a local variable on the stack, you are blowing the stack on Windows.  And, as

I think your function should return a status to indicate whether it was successful or not, so I've changed the return type to `int` and use `0` to indicate success and `-1` for failure.

That means your code needs to become more like:

```
enum { BUFFER_SIZE = 1310720 };

int read_input_file(FILE *stream, char *buffer)
{
    long i = 0;
    unsigned char *temp = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    unsigned char *calc = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);

    if (temp == NULL || calc == NULL)
    {
        free(temp);   // Free both in case only one was allocated
        free(calc);
        return -1;
    }

    if (fread(calc, BUFFER_SIZE, 1, stream) != 1)
    {
        free(temp);
        free(calc);
        return -1;
    }


    for (size_t i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = round(calc[i] / 128);  //this is an example
    }
    
    memcpy(buffer, temp, BUFFER_SIZE);
    free(temp);
    free(calc);
    return 0;
}
```

I would be happier if the length of `buffer` were passed to the function for checking, but that's a decision you can make.  It isn't crucial.  You could also use the length argument instead of the fixed size (now in the enumerated value) to make your code more general.  However, you may not need that generality at the moment.

It also isn't clear that you can't do away with `temp` (aka `tmp_buf`) by using:

```
calc[i] = round(calc[i] / 128.0);
```

Note the conversion to a floating-point constant; otherwise, there's nothing to round as the division will be an integer division.  However, if the non-example calculation uses other elements of `calc` than just `calc[i]`, then you do need the second array to hold the results.

Comment: Thanks for the help that works fine now, also didn't know that about the floating point for division, and yes I use other element of ```calc``` so a temporary buffer is needed :)